# How can I view the all properties and methods of document object in JavaScript in google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, dom, document

It is possible to view all the properties and methods of window object in JavaScript in google chrome. But it doesn't work the same way with document object. It only shows the HTML code in console.

How is it possible to view prototype of document object in chrome console?

Comment: You can use `console.dir(someElement);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use console.dir(). 
This will display all the properties of a specified JavaScript object.
For more information you can visit :- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/dir